# How do I disable administrator prompt in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, security, administrator, uac

I am using Windows 8 Enterprise on my development machine. Most of the time, I need full administrator for debugging, changing system files, etc.

In Windows 7, setting UAC to "never notify" would disable any administrator prompts.
In Windows 8 this is no longer the case. Even with UAC disabled I get prompted to grant programs elevated privileges.

Is there a way disable this behaviour?

*Note: I am fully aware of the repercussions. I have antivirus, firewall, etc and am generally quite careful about what I download or install on my machine.*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you go to Administrative Tools → Local Security Policy, navigate to to Local Policies → Security Options, in the left side of the window, and scroll down to the button.

You should be able to disable User Account Control completely.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Got it working by setting "User Account Control: Turn on Admin Approval Mode" to `Disabled`.

Comment: Sadly this also disables the ability to launch any "Metro" App at all.

Comment: Its not sad, Its a Windows feature, makes my day to disable the app model.

Comment: Anyone know/confirm if this will work on the "Home" version of Windows 8?

Comment: @Arnold where did you find that setting? I could not locate that.

Comment: Setting "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin approval mode." to disabled and rebooting did the trick for me. I no longer get applications complaining I should have started in admin mode or approval requests when copying files.

Comment: Where did you find this? I have scoured through the control panel, yet couldn't find any link to 'Local security policy' or 'Administrative tools'.

Comment: You should be able to find it here: Control Panel --> System and Security --> Administrative Tools --> Local Secutiry Policy.

Comment: @poepje You need Windows 8 Pro to find it.

Comment: @RuudLenders That must be it then, thanks. Too bad though :p

Comment: For those that don't have Windows 8 Pro, the same config is in the registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` and then `EnableLUA`. Set the value to `0`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work under 8.1 Pro. The policy is disabled (by default), but the prompts are still present.

Answer (score 2):

Open a Command Prompt and enter "shutdown /r /o" this will take a moment or two but eventually it will open up a menu.  Choose Troubleshooting -> Advanced Options -> Startup Settings.

The OS will then begin restarting.  Once it's started it will list another set of options.  Choose "Safe Mode" and continue.

Once the OS has fully restarted and your at the login screen, login to the account labeled "Administrator"

From here, open command prompt once again, running it as Administrator (right click -> Run as Admin) and enter this command "net user Administrator /active:yes"

Reboot the operating system once more and let it boot up normally.  Now when you login, login and use the Administrator account and you should never be prompted for UAC.

Comment: Do the step "login to the account labeled Administrator"  will need Admin login ?

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10, you will need to set the policy "**User Account Control:** ***Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode***" to security setting "***Elevate without prompting***".

To set this property : Go to Administrative Tools → Local Security Policy, navigate to to Local Policies → Security Options;

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how to set this?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work under 8.1 Pro either.