# "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file." error on windows 8, WITH JUST INSTALLATION EXE , NOT executable shortcuts

Tags: windows-8, administrator, uac, installation-package

I am the Admin on windows 8 enterprise, I have my UAC prompt turned off. I ALWAYS (regardless of UAC prompt settings) receive this error when running ALL EXE files which are only installation packages but no problem with running EXE shortcut of already installed apps.

The error is: " Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

I can't post the image as I need 10 reputation points but the title bar of error window states the address of my "temp" folder which sounds that must be accessible during installation process.

I can bypass the error by right click and Run As Administrator. but I don't want this.

I need to make it as default in my system so that no more right click is needed. Moreover I would be able to run them from inside IDM download list where no Run As Administrator is found in its right click menu.

your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: indows 8 changed how UAC works. Even if you disable it, its still turned on, whats disabled is the elevation prompts.  You have to disable it through a [group policy change](http://superuser.com/questions/464758/how-do-i-disable-administrator-prompt-in-windows-8?rq=1)

Comment: Are you on a work computer or your personal home machine?

Comment: thanks for the link, I did the same changes and restarted the system but this is not doing the job. still have the problem.

Comment: I am using my laptop. Installed win 8 myself and am the only user.

Comment: Is there any possibility of problems with temp folder access privileges, as I noticed that the title bar of my error notification window states the address of my temp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in changing a registry key which exactly does what I need but some side effects too. Thanks to [user1832687](https://superuser.com/users/190965/user1832687) I was able to fully disable UAC in windows 8.

I went to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

And found:

```
Ena‌​bleLUA
```

and changed the value from `1` to `0`

closed the Registry Edit window and rebooted.

Results:

1. I don't receive any UAC prompt over running any EXE file, whether or
   not it is installation package and whether or not it is being run
   through other places than windows explorer, e.g IDM download list.
2. I still have "Run As Administrator" visible and functional in my
   right clicks context menu
3. And finally and most importantly, on running exe installation files, THE ERROR BELOW NO LONGER HIT MY SCREEN:

> " Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may
>   not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

Side Effect:

I can't run any metro app! any idea?

Comment: In my opinion, disabling UAC is a really bad idea. There's a reason why computers with UAC turned off are far more prone to malware infestations than computers with UAC turned on. That being said, from your question it seems to me that the problem you're facing has to have something to do with [incorrect NTFS permissions set for the "Temp" folder](http://goo.gl/fCt2F2). If you have Adobe Acrobat XI installed, that could be [the reason for the permissions reset](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5033519).

Comment: @Vinayak yes I have acrobat XI installed. Is there any solution to revert those changes without uninstalling the program?

Comment: The solution is to either buy the software or uninstall it. From [what I gather](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/3387-73-temp-folder-writing-permission-itself#10476976) this problem only affects people who have [pirated versions](http://www.sabernova.com/2013/12/cracked-adobe-acrobat-xi-will-revert.html) of Acrobat XI installed

Comment: Can it be solved by uninstalling and reinstalling on different partition?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't help you if you use pirated software.