# I just want to disable the UAC prompt not the UAC itself. how?

Tags: windows-8.1, uac

[How do I disable administrator prompt in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/464758/how-do-i-disable-administrator-prompt-in-windows-8)

The first answer above. I can't find "Local Security Policy"

[image]

OS: W 8.1

Comment: In Start search, start to type Local Security Policy and it will appear

Comment: You do understand if you disable the prompt this will disable Windows Store applications.  You cannot fully disable UAC in Windows 8.0 and above anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running Windows 8.1 **PRO** or **Enterprise**

You can verify this by check `Windows edition`
[image]

If so, the shortcut from `Administrative Tools` may be missing, you can run `gpedit.msc` from command prompt to open `Local Security Policy`