# windows 8 running cmd as administrator without getting a pop up message

Tags: windows-8, administrator

I can run cmd as admin by right click and then clicking "run as administrator". But then windows gives me a pop message asking if "do you want following program to make changes to your computer"...

How can I avoid the popup message and then clicking yes? I have one more program "oracle vm virtualbox" that I want to run without getting the pop up message.

How to do the same?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to disable UAC only for a couple programs. [This](http://superuser.com/q/464758/380318) will do it for all programs though.

Comment: I tried the first answer. But i was not able to disable...I am using my office pc

Comment: "I am using my office pc" - Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [old Task scheduler trick, which I use since Vista](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/135472-faq-what-is-the-uac-part2/).

Go to Task scheduler Library and make a right click and click "`New Folder`" and type in "`myTasks`" to create a new folder.

Go to the folder and create a new task, select the checkbox "`Run with highest priviligies`". Give it a name like **`autoElevatePROGRAMNAME`**, go to the tab "`Actions`" and select the program you want to execute.

Now create a shortcut on the desktop with this content:

```
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN "myTasks\autoElevatePROGRAMNAME"
```

Now always start the programs with this link.

If this is too complicated, [use the Tool UACPass](https://sites.google.com/site/freeavvarea/UACPass-en) which does all steps for you.

[image]

Comment: I tried your method. The program that i want to execute is at `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` But when i click on the shortcut, a window opens and immediately closes. I am not sure if anything happens. Also the link `http://freeavvarea.r00t.la/UACPass-en`doesnt work :(

Comment: I fixed the link.

Comment: IMO this falls under the category [When people ask for security holes as features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/tag/when-people-ask-for-security-holes-as-features). Security-wise this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart no, because you need to elevate the task scheduler first when create the task via UAC prompt. so if you have no idea stop trolling

Comment: It was not my intent to antagonize but simply to point out a potential security hole (_caveat emptor_, as it were).