# Windows 10 and Security

Tags: windows-10, security

I don't want to see any Windows 10 security stuff anywhere. I already disabled UAC, and made my account Admin.  However, I still get security prompts with networking my three PCs together as well as pop-ups that say I don't have access to this or that until I select "continue".

How do I rid my PC of this stuff? No one uses my PC, there is nothing of value on my PC, and it is hard for me to read stuff about how to do this and that with the security features of Windows 10.

I miss the ease on Windows 3.1 and how i could simply right click a drive on other PC and select map.

Thank you,
DReeves

Tried to look at the "exact duplicate this was marked as, but then i remember, i have never been on this site before and therefore, it cannot be an "exact duplicate". Someone may have asked a similar question of which i was unable to locate, and would gladly look at it and try and get the answers i need. Thank you.

Comment: What you want is not actually possible.  There is no way to get Windows 10 to act like Windows 7 from a security perspective.  The lowest UAC setting on UAC is different then the lowest UAC setting on Wndows 7.

Comment: Does your computer connect to the internet?

Comment: Yes it is on the internet, and i am full aware of what is lurking beyond my modem. I have been using the internet since Hayes released the 2400 baud smart modem, and my experience with PC's in general, predates IBM being adopted as a standard. Somewhere though, when Microsoft went to the NT platform, i didnt have the energy nor desire to learn it's security stuff, and that has manifested to where i am now, the transition from Pre Windows 95 to now is too much for my simple minded head to absorb and make sense out of.

Comment: Then not only as you asking for the impossible, you are asking for the unwise. The duplicate does not mean you have asked the same question, but that someone else has, or that the answer to another question is the right answer for your question too, which is the case here. The answer to the linked duplicate question contains the only way to lower Win10 security settings as low as you desire. But don't. UAC is not a annoyance any longer. It is a "are you sure you want this program to perform this action" and it while prompt this for most program installs, including those you didn't trigger.

Answer (score -1):

You could downgrade your OS, or try a new one, like Linux. You could also "go to Administrative Tools → Local Security Policy, navigate to to Local Policies → Security Options, in the left side of the window, and scroll down to the button." [How do I disable administrator prompt in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/464758/how-do-i-disable-administrator-prompt-in-windows-8)

Comment: I did find the link from another answer to do this in Windows 8, and it also about the same in Windows 10, did that and will see what happens! Thank you for the replies!